# Testing recompose with enzyme - accessing props issue

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, recompose

So I've searched for an answer and have yet to find one that fits my use case. I'm a little new to testing with Jest/Enzyme and very new to testing with recompose.

I don't know how to test my functional Component, which is created using recompose. I can't seem to figure out how to access the props (state and handler functions) in my test.

Here's an example of my functional Component, I'll call **UserDetails**

```
const UserDetails = ({
 userInfo,
 onUserInfoUpdate,
 className,
 error,
 title,
 primaryBtnTitle,
 submit,
 secondaryBtnTitle,
 secondaryBtnFunc,
 ...props
}) => (
 <div className={className}>
   <div className="user-details-body">
     <Section title="User details">
       <TextInput
         caption="First Name"
         value={userInfo.first}
         onChange={onUserInfoUpdate('first')}
         name="first-name"
         min="1"
         max="30"
         autoComplete="first-name"
       />
       <TextInput
         caption="Last Name"
         value={userInfo.last}
         onChange={onUserInfoUpdate('last')}
         name="last-name"
         min="1"
         max="30"
         autoComplete="last-name"
       />
     </Section>
   </div>

   <div className="errorBar">
     {error && <Alert type="danger">{error}</Alert>}
   </div>

   <ActionBar>
     <ButtonGroup>
       <Button type="secondary" onClick={secondaryBtnFunc}>
         {secondaryBtnTitle}
       </Button>
       <Button type="primary" onClick={submit}>
         {primaryBtnTitle}
       </Button>
     </ButtonGroup>
   </ActionBar>
 </div>
```

Here is example code of my **index.js** file that composes my withState and withHandlers to my Component:

```
import UserDetails from './UserDetails'
import { withState, withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose'

export default compose(
  withState('error', 'updateError', ''),
  withState('userInfo', 'updateUserInfo', {
    first: '',
    last: '',
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onUserInfoUpdate: ({ userInfo, updateUserInfo }) => key => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      updateCardInfo({
        ...cardInfo,
        [key]: e.target.value,
      })
    },
    submit: ({ userInfo, submitUserInfo }) => key => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      submitUserInfo(userInfo) 
      //submitUserInfo is a graphQL mutation
      })
    }  
  }) 
)
```

Now I'm trying to write tests for this component. I import the index file that has the Component wrapped to create an HOC.

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme' 
import UserDetails from './'

describe('UserDetails Element', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    const tree = mount( <UserDetails /> )
  console.log(tree.props());
  })
})
```

The console log gives me this in the terminal

```
{ children: 
  { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: 
      { [Function: WithState]
        displayName: 'withState(withState(withHandlers((UserDetails)))))' },
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: {},
      _owner: null,
      _store: {} } }
```

I get the same output if I console.log `tree.props('userInfo')`. I get undefined if I console.log `tree.prop('userInfo')` or `tree.props().userInfo`

Also, when I try to use my handlers in the test file, I get an error that the method is undefined.

Where am I going wrong? **Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test loads the *enhanced* component, not the underlying *bare* `UserDetails` component. So what you see with `console.log` are the props of the outermost component (`compose`). You can get a hold of inner components using `tree.find(UserDetails)`.

To do that you will have to import both files in your test:

```
import UserDetails from './'
import BareUserDetails from './UserDetails'
```

and `find` it this way

```
const tree = mount( <UserDetails /> )
const innerDetails = tree.find(BareUserDetails);
```

`enzyme`'s `find` does not always find what you want the way you expected. Experiment with the various options that `find` offers.

Comment: ah, amazing. I will give this a shot and report back. Thank you for responding!

Comment: thanks for the reply, it worked! Now I need to figure out how to use those functions in my test file.